# how to retrieve resource file in flex

Tags: apache-flex, resources, air, resourcebundle

I am using local connection to connect between two air applications. From one air application (say App-B) How can I retrieve the resource bundle (properties file) of another air application (say App-A) and save it to the disk.

Thanks,
Tamil

Comment: Do you control both applications?

Comment: yes. I do. I can make code level changes to both the applications.